# Parceler and SimpleXml as stated in Parceler's readme

Tags: java, android, simple-framework, parceler

Parceler's readme states that it can be used with other POJO based libraries, in particular SimpleXML.

Are there any examples available demonstrating the usage?

I've used Parceler with GSON successfully:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
ParcelerObj parcelerObj = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, ParcelerObj.class);
String str = gson.toJson(parcelerObj);
```

However, I'm not sure where to start with SimpleXML. I currently have the following SimpleXML class:

```
@Root(name="point")
@Order(attributes={"lat", "lon", " alt"})
public class SensorLocation {
    @Attribute
    private double lat;

    @Attribute
    private double lon;

    @Attribute
    private double alt;

    public SensorLocation (
        @Attribute(name="lat") double lat,
        @Attribute(name="lon") double lon,
         @Attribute(name="alt") double alt
    ) {
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lon = lon;
        this.alt = alt;
    }
}
```

This class can then be serialized into the following XML

```
<point lat="10.1235" lon="-36.1346" alt="10.124"/>
```

Using the following code:

```
SensorLocation sl = new SensorLocation (10.1235, -36.1346, 10.124);
Serializer s = new Persister();
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
s.write(sl, out);
```

I currently have a strange requirement to keep XML attributes and elements in particular order. That's why I'm using `@Order`.

How would Parceler work with SimpleXML? Would I pass Parceler instance into Serializer.write()?

If anyone can point me to a resource, I can do my own research. I just couldn't find any starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of your bean that supports both SimpleXML and Parceler:

```
@Parcel
@Root(name="point")
@Order(attributes={"lat", "lon", " alt"})
public class SensorLocation {
    @Attribute
    private double lat;

    @Attribute
    private double lon;

    @Attribute
    private double alt;

    @ParcelConstructor
    public SensorLocation (
        @Attribute(name="lat") double lat,
        @Attribute(name="lon") double lon,
        @Attribute(name="alt") double alt
    ) {
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lon = lon;
        this.alt = alt;
    }
}
```

Worth noting, this configuration of Parceler will use reflection to access your bean's fields.  Using non-private fields will avoid a warning and a slight performance hit.

Usage:

```
SensorLocation sl = new SensorLocation (10.1235, -36.1346, 10.124);
Parcelable outgoingParcelable = Parceler.wrap(sl);
//Add to intent, etc.

//Read back in from incoming intent
Parcelable incomingParcelable = ...
SensorLocation sl = Parceler.unwrap(incomingParcelable);
Serializer s = new Persister();
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
s.write(sl, out);
```

Because Parceler doesn't introduce any code into your bean you're free to do with it what you want.

Comment: Wow, nice, that is such an easy application of it!